# Is it possible to "fix" cells similar to the page break at Word?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two Google Sheets files (Source file 1 and 2) and I import the data below each other on a single file with Importrange.
It's build like that:

Content of source file 1: Row 1-10
Then 9 rows with no content
Content of source file 2: Row 20-30

Sometimes, in Source file 1 a row will be added so that it's gonna be row 1-11. But then, the content of source file 2 will also move from 21-31.
How can I manage for the content of source file 2 to stay in row 20-30? This is similar to the page break in Word where I can keep on typing on page 1 and page 2 won't move.

I appreciate every help! Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple straight answer is you can't relationally connect/interlink a `dynamic importrange data`(from sheet 1) with a `static` section of your Sheet 2.

You could also look into `[google-apps-script]` to bypass importrange function totally.

---

Now here's a workaround which is ***not-so-ideal*** approach but nonetheless you can give it a shot and see if it is something that's feasible for ya.

- As shown in the screenshot (to the left) maintain a column to accommodate sequence
  of numbers in `Column_A`. when ever you insert a new row in b/w existing rows
  increment the existing max value in that row by `1`. 11 and 12 are
  newly inserted rows in the screenshot.
- Also to not get confused by what number should be entered when new
  row is created, you can see the cell `C1` showing the max value in
  `Column_A`. so you just enter 13 next.

  C1 formula: `=max(A2:A)`
- Now coming to the second sheet you have a static sequence of numbers
  in `Column A`. `Column B` has the following formula which links the data
  to respective numbers irrespective of new rows addition at random spots
  in source sheet
- B2 formula:
  `=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ax,IMPORTRANGE("[SPREADSHEET ID]","Sheet2!A:B"),2,)))))`

[image]